# Need an int to be empty (not 0) for FTP login in C#

Tags: c#

I have a legacy C# program that gets files from an FTP site in a certain directory

```
string FeedFile = FTPOp.(
      "ftp.XXXXXX.com",*NORMALLY PORT GOES IN HERE*, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", 
      String.Format(" /Documents/Vendor/acknowledgements/{0}", FeedFile),
      String.Format(RootDirectory + Name + "\\Input\\" + FeedFile)
);
```

I have set up several of these for different vendors without issue, but in this particular case there is no port number for the FTP site. It is blank. **FeedFile** format is Site(string), port(int), username(string), password(string), Directory we pick up from(string). (The lack of port is not an issue using our JSON routines, go figure)

- If I leave the int space where the port number should be as blank,
  Argument missing
- If I try to put port:    , argument missing
- If I try to enclose the int space with double quotes, I am trying pass a string
  where there should be an int and it errors.
- If I remove that space, everything shifts back one space and Username is in the int spot and
  password is in the Username spot and it errors twice.

Is there anything simple I can do here to pass null or empty parameter where the port (int) should be in C#?

Comment: By default, FTP is on port `21`. What if you just tried that? If that doesn't work, do you have any way to access this FTP site directly, or have a point of contact that manages it? Because beyond those, there's probably not much any of us can do to divine the correct port number. Plus, your code seems to be something internal to your company - C# doesn't have built-in FTP functionality/libraries that look like what you're using.

Comment: It is C# that is not allowing me to pass a blank field. We pass a blank field in JSON routines and they connect up just fine. Filezilla connects up just fine with a blank port. I can also connect through a command prompt without a port and pull files manually. But  perhaps you are correct that there is a default port somewhere that this FTP site uses. That is at least something I can search for and I thank you for the comment.

Comment: I meant you could just use `21` as your actual argument, like `string FeedFile = FTPOp.(
      "ftp.XXXXXX.com", 21, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD",  ...)` Any software that connects to FTP (like Filezilla) without a port specified is going to use 21 by default, but the code you're using looks like it always needs explicit port specification no matter what.